# CGImageCreateWithMask works great but the masked out area is black in my resulting image, how can I set it to be white?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I've masked out my image thusly:

```
    CGImageRef maskRef = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"testMask2.png"] CGImage];

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), nil, YES);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);

imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
```

And it works great, but the resulting image has BLACK where it was masked out, how can I set it to have WHITE where its masked out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are masking JPEG image which does not have alpha channel this will happen (black background instead of transparent).

So you need to do something like this before masking:

```
    CGImageRef imageNoAlpha = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noAlphaImage.jpg"].CGImage;

CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imageNoAlpha);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imageNoAlpha);

CGContextRef ctxWithAlpha = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, 8, 4*width, cs, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGContextDrawImage(ctxWithAlpha, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageNoAlpha);

CGImageRef imageWithAlpha = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctxWithAlpha);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageWithAlpha, mask);
```

...

Be sure to release created images, context and colorspace ...

Comment: There is a small typo for height, it is getting the width instead

Answer (score 0):

The image is supposed to be transparent where it's "masked out"; the colour you see will depend on what background you're drawing it on.

(I don't remember if there's a requirement that the source image has an alpha channel.)

It may be worth making sure that `imageView.opaque = NO`.

Comment: I set the imageView background's alpha to 0 and opaque to NO but still get black, I wonder if the blackness is at the CGImage level, like I have to draw it to a context.

Comment: Shizam: the "blackness" is whatever is under the image view then. or if it's transparent, whatever's under that. it's turtles all the way down!

Comment: Nah, as a test I created png with transparency and put it in that imageView and it showed through to the background color (blue) but if I put the resulting masked image in there its still black.  I went through a longer operation to create a bitmapContext and draw the image into it and THEN use the resulting context as the source for an image, that did correctly have alpha punched through it.  Weird.

Comment: Yeah, very weird (it should be hidden if alpha is 0). Perhaps using a CGImage-with-mask as "layer content" isn't supported?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imageView.opaque = NO;
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Also, the image used to mask should be black and white (not transparent).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. The solution is pretty simple:
It is the best to create graphic context for masking this way:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(maskFrame.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect ff =  CGRectMake(0, 0, maskFrame.size.width, mask.size.height);
CGContextClipToMask(ctx, ff, mask.CGImage);
....
```

Make sure, the second parameter in **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions** is set to **NO** (which means none-opaque context).
Another benefit is that this creation function automatically scales context to retina displays.