# Change image in iOS using mask color

Tags: ios, uiimage, graphicscontext

How to change image from

[image]

to

[image]

Thanks for any help and answer!

Comment: I try using CGColorSpaceRef and CGContext for UIImage but i don't know how it work.

Comment: You may find some more useful information in this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848430/cgimagecreatewithmask-works-great-but-the-masked-out-area-is-black-in-my-resulti

Comment: I need clean background and create mask with other image object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For image processing I can use:

1. OpenGL|ES (this is hard way)
2. OpenCV library (using C/C++)
3. Core Image CIFilter (only iOS 5.0 supported)
4. NYXImagesKit