# Fade Image to Transparent in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am just starting out with iOS development. I'm trying to determine if this is possible in iOS and I'm new enough that I don't know what to search for, so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm going to be saving a few images in the application and the primary image will fade over another image like so:

[image: Image A fading over top Image B]

Image A will still need to be a solid image, so my question "Is it possible to create a gradient mask that only fades for 50px from the bottom (transparent) of an image?"

Sorry if this is a basic question and since I don't know where to start I don't have any code to request help on. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

You will need to draw the images in a CGContext. Basically you would first draw image b first then draw image 'a' with an alpha mask using CGImageCreateWithMask.

It is very straight forward. See here for an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848430/cgimagecreatewithmask-works-great-but-the-masked-out-area-is-black-in-my-resulti).

Comment: So it sounds like I would create an image that faded white (bottom) to black (top), then apply this as a mask and apply that mask to my Image A? Cool. Thanks for the direction!